# Convert MySQL update SQL statement to Oracle update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, inner-join

I have query which is working fine with *MySQL*, but if I execute it in Oracle database I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly
```

MySQL query:

```
UPDATE  T1 
  INNER JOIN  T2 ON  T1.UIDPK =T2.UIDFK
  SET T1.C1=CONCAT('EMPTY_',T2.UID) WHERE T2.C1 IS NULL ;
```

Changed query for Oracle:

```
 UPDATE 
(
 SELECT T1.C1 AS OLD ,CONCAT('EMPTY_',T2.UID) AS NEW FROM  T1 
 INNER JOIN  T2 ON T1.UIDPK= T2.UIDFK WHERE T1.C1 IS NULL
) T3
SET T3.OLD = T3.NEW
```

Above query is not working in Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

The update syntax you are using only works if your version of Oracle decides that the subquery aliased as `T3` is an updatable view.  You may use a correlated subquery instead of this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET C1 = (SELECT CONCAT('EMPTY_', T2.UID) FROM T2
          WHERE T1.UIDPK = T2.UIDFK AND T2.C1 IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if you have indexes on `T2.UIDFK` and `T1.UIDP` columns.

If not, create them and your update might work after that.

*Not having indexes on those columns would result in this error / restriction.*

**Note:**

You can always delete those indexes after this update, although it would seem that those are intended as a foreign key and a primary key column, respectively, and it's always good to have created FK and PK constraints on such columns (which would also lead to existing indexes on those columns).